# Backbone View - Trigger events depending on a dynamic className

Tags: javascript, web-applications, backbone.js

Mates, I've got the following code:

```
App.Views.Bed = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'li',
template: _.template( App.Templates.Bed ),

events: {
    'click .booked': 'showReservation',
    'click .occupied': 'showGuest',
    'click .free': 'checkIn'
},

render: function(){
    if( this.model.get('id_bookings') ){
        this.clase = 'booked';
    }
    if( this.model.get('id_guests') ){
        this.clase = 'occupied';
    }else{
        this.clase = 'free';
    }
    this.$el.addClass(this.clase).html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );

    return this;
},

checkIn: function(){
    console.log('Check-in form load');
},

showReservation: function(){

},

showGuest: function(){

}

});
```

I'm trying to trigger a different method depending on the className (which I set depending on the content's model).

Is there a way to filter by classes when defining a view's events?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it's not possible using the declarative `events` hash, unless you're willing to do some `:parent` selector hacks, and I'm not sure if that's even possible, either.

The problem is that any jQuery selector you use to define the element (for example the class selector `.booked`) is applied **within** the view´s `el`, so the element's own class is not considered in the selector.

Instead I would dynamically set the handler method. Something like:

```
events: {
    'click': 'onClick'
},

render: function(){
    if( this.model.get('id_bookings') ){
        this.clase = 'booked';
        this.onClick = this.showReservation;
    }
    if( this.model.get('id_guests') ){
        this.clase = 'occupied';
        this.onClick = this.showGuest;
    }else{
        this.clase = 'free';
        this.onClick = this.checkIn;
    }
    _.bindAll(this, 'onClick');

    this.$el.addClass(this.clase).html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
    return this;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. You just need to set one click handler for your button and let it proxy to the right method.

```
App.Views.Bed = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: _.template( App.Templates.Bed ),

    events: {
        'click': 'click_handler'
    },

    render: function(){
        if( this.model.get('id_bookings') ){
            this.clase = 'booked';
        }
        if( this.model.get('id_guests') ){
            this.clase = 'occupied';
        }else{
            this.clase = 'free';
        }
        this.$el.addClass(this.clase).html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );

        return this;
    },

    click_handler: function() {
        if (this.$el.hasClass('booked')) {
            this.showReservation();
        } else if (this.$el.hasClass('occupied')) {
            this.showGuest();
        } else if (this.$el.hasClass('free')) {
            this.checkIn();
        } else {
            // oops!?
        }
    },

    checkIn: function(){
        console.log('Check-in form load');
    },

    showReservation: function(){

    },

    showGuest: function(){

    }
});
```